# Sqlalchemy event loop closed

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

i was messing around with the sqlalchemy ORM functionality

i was able to make it work on my main app but when i created a separate file `test.py` to test something, i kept getting event loop closed errors:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x7f7041c07310>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/krypt/Documents/Projects/app/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 1072, in __del__
  File "/home/krypt/Documents/Projects/app/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 298, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 700, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

here is the code for `test.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.future import select
from sqlalchemy import delete
import asyncio

Base = declarative_base()

class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    string = Column(String(30))
    prefix = Column(String(1), default = "!")




async def main():
    engine = create_async_engine("mariadb+aiomysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname")
    session = AsyncSession(engine)

    stmt = select(Table).where(Table.prefix == "!")

    res = await session.execute(stmt)
    row = res.scalars().first()

    print(row)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that aiomysql is trying to close its connection after the event loop has closed.  I could make the code in the question work by ensuring that the session was closed and the engine disposed.

```py
async def main():
    engine = create_async_engine("mariadb+aiomysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname")
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:

        stmt = select(Table).where(Table.prefix == "!")

        res = await session.execute(stmt)
        row = res.scalars().first()

        print(row)
    await engine.dispose()
```

There's some discussion about this [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/5994) (towards the end); explicitly closing and disposing is the recommended workaround to prevent the connection's `__del__` method executing after the event loop has closed.

Comment: Ah, i see. i was running one even loop that instantiated the sessions that are to be used in further code (for a discord bot).
when that main event loop ends i want to use discord.py's `client.run` method to start my discord bot, but i cant actually run it in a already running event loop.
do you have any ideas on a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm afraid not - I don't use async much, and discord not at all.  I think you should ask a new question explaining what you are trying to do.